# How do I make sure FCM notification?

Tags: android

I already finished developing FCM service in ANDROID Studio with simulator by using PHP server. The simulator works well, but when I install the app, FCM pushing works successfully with device token, but my device cannot receive FCM notification.

Why the problem happens?

Only FCM works in ANDROID Studio simulator...not real device.

Comment: check if the registration token is valid

Comment: Tagging may help in finding a knowledgeable audience - didn't find FCM, cant myself tell firebase to be appropriate. As is, this question is quite broad - how does `device cannot receive FCM notification` manifest on the server side and on the device side?

Comment: I verify my token.... also php server says it push notification successfully. @shashankchandak